# Get Page Title In PHTML? CE 2.4

Tags: phtml, magento2.4, page-title

I'm struggling with something simple.

I'm trying to print the Page Title in the custom block from my custom.phtml and I'm getting nothing.

I've removed the Magento original page title block from all pages by updating default.xml

**referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"**

I've created my own block and pointed it to my phtml file in the same default.xml

**block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="page_title" template="Magento_Theme::page_title.phtml"**

Now the problem is even if i copy paste the contents of original **/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml**

into my custom **page_title.phtml** I'm getting nothing, 0.
It's not the case of caching or anything similar as any other type of content gets displayed no problem. :(

All I'm looking for is a way to access that **$titleHtml** variable from **title.phtml** somehow...
Any help? :(

Comment: btw how do i format markup on stackexchange??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look for the string 'page.main.title' in vendor/magento folder, you will see that the title is set within the layout; for instance, below:

```
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument translate="true" name="page_title" xsi:type="string">Compare Products</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
```

So, since you have removed this reference, there is no instruction your block has to perform.

I have myself come up with something by using the below:

```
<block name="page.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="page_heading" xsi:type="string">My Custom Title</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

If you want to make you content dynamic,then just add either a helper or a class and you will be able to extend this further

Comment: oh dear, i just grep'ed for page.main.title and didn't realised it shows up in soo many places :O

i initially just grep'ed for htmlClass="page-title-wrapper" and only saw title.phtml referenced from that

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->getPageTitle();
```

Happy coding

Comment: I've tried and but got an exception with a huge stack trace :?
magento is hard lol. thank you